# How to get applied coupon details in magento 2.1

Tags: magento2

I need to get applied coupon details in cart **form.phtml**

```
/app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart
```

In this path we have shopping cart files are there like **coupon.html, form.html**

In a coupon.html file we have code to get coupon

```
 $block->escapeHtml($block->getCouponCode())
```

How to get this coupon detail in other **phtml** file **form.phtml**

Answer (score 0):

In block you can use the following code

```
$getCouponObj = $block->getLayout()
->createBlock('Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Coupon');

 echo $getCouponObj->getCouponCode(); //applied coupon code

 echo $getCouponObj->getAmount(); //applied coupon amount
```